# Accessing global variables with node.js and CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, global-variables

I'm trying to declare global variables for my applications that I'm writing using Node.js and CoffeeScript. So I'm declaring it in a common file that is concatenated to both applications after compilation. In that file I have for example:

```
root = exports ? this
root.myVariable = 300
```

So my first application is a HTML one. When I try to access this variable, for example by

```
console.log myVariable
```

There is no problem with it. But my other application is a server application lauched by node command and I cannot access that variable in that application. I tried:

```
console.log root.myVariable
console.log myVariable
```

With first line I'm getting 'undefined' printed (so it looks that root is defined) and with the second one, I'm getting ReferenceError - myVariable is undefined.

So how can I access this variable?

Here is an output code in Javascript that I get, I guess it might be helpful:

```
(function() {
  var root, _ref;

  root = (_ref = typeof module !== "undefined" && module !== null ? module.exports : void 0) != null ? _ref : this;

  root.myVariable = 300;

}).call(this);

(function() {

  console.log(root.myVariable);

  console.log(myVariable);

}).call(this);
```

Comment: You want to declare a global (generally mutable) variable in `node.js`, or you want to declare a constant (immutable) variable, that'll be accessible both from client and server js?

Comment: @leonid-beschastny Well, actually it should be a constant value read from both applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but you need to change things just a little bit

```coffee
# config.coffee
module.exports =
  foo: "bar"
  hello: "world"
  db:
    user: alice
    pass: password1

# lib/a.coffee
config = require "../config"

# lib/b.coffee
config = require "../config"

# lib/db.coffee
dbconfig = require("../config").db
```

Comment: `module.exports` will trow an exception on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Client and server `JavaScript` (or `CoffeeScript`) works differently. So, its a really difficult to write a module that'll work in both applications.

There is a lot of libraries to solve this problem, like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).

But I have two simpler suggestions for your problem.

---

First one is to use `JSON` to store your global constants. On the server side you can simply `require` you `JSON` file:

```
root = require './config.json'
```

On the client side you may either parse it manually or serve it as `pjson`.

---

My second suggestion is to write really simple module that'll be compatible with both your applications. It'll look something like this:

```
root = 
  myVariable: 300
  myOtherVariable: 400

modulte.exports = root if module?.parent?
```

This code should be compatible with both `node.js` `require` function and browser `<script>` tag.

## Update:

I just reread you question and realized, that you've did almost as I suggested. But your code looks fine to me. You may try to use `module.export` instead of its alias `exports`, it may help:

```
root = modulte?.exports ? this
root.myVariable = 300
```

But, as I said, your code looks fine to me as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but unfortunately the result is still the same after using module.export. I updated my question with an output after Coffeescript compilation, maybe it could be useful.

Comment: @krajol, have you required your module before accessing it from your server code? `root = require './root.coffee'`?